# How to move Azure blobs to other subscription

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to move Azure blobs to another subscription (the blobs are mostly images).

What are my options? Many thanks.

Comment: this already answered post might help u.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582145/copying-storage-data-from-one-azure-account-to-another

Comment: Yup - look at the answer @Zafar pointed to. Also has link to info on brand new cross-account blob-copy functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RedGate Cloud Servies](https://cloudservices.red-gate.com) todo that (no affiliations). They have a feature were you can sync two storage accounts. Best of all **it's free** the first 10 days. If you just need an inital copy you can basically do it for free.

This is how you do it:

1. Go to:
   https://cloudservices.red-gate.com/
2. Register (Free)
3. Go to:
   https://cloudservices.red-gate.com/Sync/AzureAzure
4. Enter your storage account data, hit continue and wait