# Migrate Azure Storage account to a different subscription

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-management

I have more than one Azure subscriptions, one for myself and others for clients.  Can I change the subscription for one of my storage accounts so that it's associated to one of my other subscriptions?

Cannot find a way to do it through the Azure Management Portal.  Perhaps it can be done with PowerShell?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicated, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67406551/7829826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're best approach would be to contact Microsoft Windows Azure support to see if they can help.

Comment: they were able to help me somewhat, but you cant change the subscription that a storage account is associated with.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to post some updated guidance in case anyone else runs into this issue.  To move a storage account, you can do it easily for V1 or V2.  You can move Classic Storage but its not easy and I would suggest upgrading it to the newer ARM based V1 or V2 storage account.  This assume within the region.  Moving to a subscription in another region is a different matter.  This answer is probably very different that it would have been back in 2014.

[Move Azure Storage account to another region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-move?tabs=azure-portal)

[Move classic storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftclassicstorage)

[Move V1 or V2 Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftstorage)

[Move to another region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-move?tabs=azure-portal)

[Migrate classic storage to ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-overview#migration-of-storage-accounts)